# How can one instance change some variable of the other instance of the same class

Tags: java, instance, pass-by-reference

I am Java beginner and I have a question. Let's say we have a class:

```
class Foo {
    public String test;

    public void someMethod() { } 
}
```

And we have two instances of this class: `bar1` and `bar2`.

Now how can I make that `bar1.someMethod()` changes the value of the `bar2.test` without passing `bar2` as parameter to the `bar`1 (no something like `bar1.someMethod(bar2)`). To clear out: I am making a game where you can move objects in turns, so I want that after the move object becomes inactive and makes other object active so only one of them can be moved at the time. Thanks.

Comment: You can probably change the value bar2 within the method and then call it as you please

Comment: Passing in a reference of `bar2` is the preferred way. Why would you not want to do this?

Comment: You really do not want to do that. You're breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Can I use some managing class then? How could I implement that?

Comment: if you are trying to make a common variable which all the class object can share, you can declare the variable as static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should solve this problem different

as you probably will have an other class playground (or whatever) put there a List for your Foos
and
add your Method `someMethod()` into this Class where you handle the state of the variable test of your class Foo

```
class playground{

  List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

 void someMethod(Foo a,Foo b){
    a.changeTest("");
    b.changeTest("");
  }
}
```

And in the class Foo you do of course the real change of the state

```
class Foo{

  void changeTest(String a){
    test = a;
  }
}
```

Comment: btw if there are only 2 states use a boolean variable

Comment: Yes, I want boolean. Can you explain one more thing? Will List<Foo> make the array of my instances of my Foo class auromaticaly?

Comment: you can also use array if you know the exact count of your foos but if you dont know use a List inside it's the same as String but if the array is full and you add another element it's expanding and copying everyting into an new array thats bigger

Comment: maybe also take a look into this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Can't do easily.

Longer:
How should `bar1` know which other instance to manipulate? There may be many instances (or only two, I don't know you application).

You could have a (private) field in class `Foo` which knows the other instance.
Or you could have a class `Foos` which knows both instances.
Another (ugly) solution would be to have two static fields in `Foo` however this is discouraged as this will prevent you from every effectively using more than two instances.

Comment: Only two instances (for now). I am thinking about some other class that manages turns but I don't know how to make that. There is mamy hot - seat games that use that idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on exactly what you mean but I've have a go. I'll explain it to you with two classes, one for your MainProgram and the other for Foo.

```
public class Foo {

    public String test;
    private Foo otherPlayer = null;

    public void someMethod() {

    } 

    public void setOtherPlayer(Foo otherPlayer) {
        this.otherPlayer = otherPlayer;
    }
}
```

I've added another method which does pass another Foo instance as a parameter, but this is the only method that will need it and it's for the purpose of setting a field (where it says **private Foo otherPlayer**) in your class instance which is accessible from all other methods in this instance.

Also, you'll notice the keyword **this**. **this.variable** means a field (a field is inside a class but outside a method) in the same instance as the calling method is in. **otherPlayer** refers to the parameter in the setOtherPlayer method.

```
public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo player1 = new Foo();
        Foo player2 = new Foo();

        player1.setOtherPlayer(player2);
        player2.setOtherPlayer(player1);
    }
}
```

Then in your MainProgram create two instances of Foo and then for both players, set the player they are competing against. This should be done before doing anything else with the players.

Comment: Programming's all about simplicity and readability. When I started Java, I developed bad code practices myself but have learnt over the last 2/3 years better ways of organising my code. Always have a class for the main program itself with the main function inside of there and then access your classes from there.

Comment: Also, get used to using different packages for organising your classes where similar classes belong to the same package. The real identity of a class is package.class. So, if you have a class call Cat and a package called animals.mammals then the class's identity is animals.mammals.Cat. You can then have two different classes called Cat, each in different packages.

Comment: I used this solution for now, its simple and works. But what I had in mind is rather some class that manages wich object can move next. So for only two objects this solution is great, but for more it starts to be complicated. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Here is a more complicated game with a variable number of players. There are many different styles of programming for games, but the one here is a simple dice game with 6 players (you can change the number of players in the code). If you roll a 1 or 2, the next player misses a turn. If you roll a 3 or 4, the players' turns are reversed. If you roll a 5 or 6, it simply moves on to the next player. Here is the code:

Comment: The code's in one of the main answers, "This is another code for multiple players". It wouldn't format the code or allow much text in one of these sub-comments.

Answer (score 1):

This is another code for multiple players

```
import java.util.Random;


public class Dice {

    public int roll() {
        return new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
    }
}


import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Display extends JFrame {

    public Display(final Game game) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        JButton btnNextMove = new JButton("Do next move");
        btnNextMove.setBounds(12, 12, 129, 25);
        getContentPane().add(btnNextMove);

        setBounds(0, 0, 162, 77);

        btnNextMove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                game.doNextMove();
            }
        });

        game.start();
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Game {
    private ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

    private Player currentPlayer = null;

    public void addPlayer(Player p) {
        players.add(p);
    }

    public void start() {
        int playerCount = players.size();

        for (int i=0; i<playerCount; i++) {
            int previousPlayerIndex = i-1;
            int nextPlayerIndex = i+1;

            // Makes the players loop round at the edges
            if (previousPlayerIndex < 0) previousPlayerIndex += playerCount;
            if (nextPlayerIndex >= playerCount) nextPlayerIndex -= playerCount;

            Player p = players.get(i);
            p.setPreviousPlayer(players.get(previousPlayerIndex));
            p.setNextPlayer(players.get(nextPlayerIndex));
        }

        // Sets current player to the first player
        setCurrentPlayer(players.get(0));
    }

    private void setCurrentPlayer(Player p) {
        this.currentPlayer = p;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("It's " + p.playerName + "'s turn to make a move.");
    }


    public void doNextMove() {
        Dice dice = new Dice();
        int value = dice.roll();

        System.out.println(currentPlayer.playerName + " rolled a " + value);

        if (value <= 2) skipPlayer();
        else if (value <= 4) reverse();
        else if (value <= 6) doNormalMove();
    }

    public void reverse() {
        int playerCount = players.size();

        for (int i=0; i<playerCount; i++) {
            players.get(i).reverseSiblingPlayers();
        }

        System.out.println("Play is reversed");
        setCurrentPlayer(currentPlayer.getNextPlayer());
    }

    public void doNormalMove() {
        System.out.println("Nothing special happens here");
        setCurrentPlayer(currentPlayer.getNextPlayer());
    }

    public void skipPlayer() {
        System.out.println(currentPlayer.getNextPlayer().playerName + " misses a turn");
        setCurrentPlayer(currentPlayer.getNextPlayer().getNextPlayer());
    }
}


public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game game = new Game();
        game.addPlayer(new Player("Player 1"));
        game.addPlayer(new Player("Player 2"));
        game.addPlayer(new Player("Player 3"));
        game.addPlayer(new Player("Player 4"));
        game.addPlayer(new Player("Player 5"));
        game.addPlayer(new Player("Player 6"));

        Display display = new Display(game);
        display.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public class Player {

    public final String playerName;

    private Player previousPlayer = null;
    private Player nextPlayer = null;

    public Player(String playerName) {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    public void setPreviousPlayer(Player previousPlayer) {
        this.previousPlayer = previousPlayer;
    }

    public void setNextPlayer(Player nextPlayer) {
        this.nextPlayer = nextPlayer;
    }

    public Player getPreviousPlayer() {
        return previousPlayer;
    }

    public Player getNextPlayer() {
        return nextPlayer;
    }

    public void reverseSiblingPlayers() {
        Player previousPlayer = this.previousPlayer;
        Player nextPlayer = this.nextPlayer;

        this.nextPlayer = previousPlayer;
        this.previousPlayer = nextPlayer;
    }
}
```

Comment: The imports are for the class following the import statements. Put all of your classes in their own files where the filenames must be FileName.java. For example, a class called Player is in a file called Player.java

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can have a Chain of your performers.

So the Chain should look like this:

```
public class Performer {

private Performer next;
private boolean active;

public perform() {
   if(isActive()) {
     switchStates();
     // do something meaningul
   } else if(next.isActive()) {
       next.perform();
   }
}

public void setActive(boolean active) {
     this.active = active.
}

private boolean isActive() {
   return active;
}

private void switchStates() {
   boolean currentState = this.active;
   next.setActive(currentState );
   this.active = !currentState;
}
```

}

**IMPL2: when performers should do different things**

```
 public void perform(Action action) {
      if(isActive()) {
          // update states and do other basic actions
          action.execute(); // executes action on current performer
      } else if(next.isActive()) {
          next.perform(action);
      }
  }
```

- IF all performers can do the same JOB, but you need to switch between
  it - create current state holder and call it from *perform()* method
  according to performer "*active*" state.  So, when some event is
  registered, you should call `perform()` method, inside it you can do
  whatever you want.
- IF your performers should do different things, you should consider
  about an "`Action`" class with different    implementations, and it
  should be passed into *perform()* method (**you can see this in IMPL2 snippet**)